# Google Speech API GRPC timeout

Tags: python, google-cloud-platform, speech-recognition, grpc

I'm writing an app that uses Google Cloud Platform's Streaming Speech Recognition API. The idea is that the main loop continuously monitors microphone input (always listening on standby) and once audio peaks above a certain threshold level, it spawns a **MicrophoneStream** class instance in order to make a speech recognition request. This is a way of bypassing **Google API**'s one minute limit on the duration of the stream. After 1 minute runs out the system either goes back on standby monitoring sound levels, or creates a new **MicrophoneStream** instance in case if someone is still talking.

The problem is that after a minute **MicrophoneStream** instance does not go quetly and throws an exception:

```
grpc._channel._Rendezvous: <_Rendezvous of RPC that terminated with 
(StatusCode.INVALID_ARGUMENT, Client GRPC deadline too short. Should be at 
least: 3 * audio-duration + 5 seconds. Current deadline is: 
188.99906457681209 second(s). Required at least: 194 second(s).)>
```

It seems like a [known bug in Google API](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/google-cloud-python/issues/3165), however I haven't found a solution anywhere. I've been searching for days trying to figure out how to change GRPC deadline settings to prevent this error. Alternatively, I would be more than happy to simply ignore it, however `try:` and `Except Exception:` don't seem to work either. Any ideas? Here's Google's sample Python implementation:

```
from __future__ import division

import re
import sys

from google.cloud import speech
from google.cloud.speech import enums
from google.cloud.speech import types
import pyaudio
from six.moves import queue

# Audio recording parameters
RATE = 16000
CHUNK = int(RATE / 10)  # 100ms


class MicrophoneStream(object):
    """Opens a recording stream as a generator yielding the audio chunks."""
    def __init__(self, rate, chunk):
        self._rate = rate
        self._chunk = chunk

        # Create a thread-safe buffer of audio data
        self._buff = queue.Queue()
        self.closed = True

    def __enter__(self):
        self._audio_interface = pyaudio.PyAudio()
        self._audio_stream = self._audio_interface.open(
            format=pyaudio.paInt16,
            channels=1, rate=self._rate,
            input=True, frames_per_buffer=self._chunk,
            stream_callback=self._fill_buffer,
        )

        self.closed = False

        return self

    def __exit__(self, type, value, traceback):
        self._audio_stream.stop_stream()
        self._audio_stream.close()
        self.closed = True
        self._buff.put(None)
        self._audio_interface.terminate()

    def _fill_buffer(self, in_data, frame_count, time_info, status_flags):
        """Continuously collect data from the audio stream, into the buffer."""
        self._buff.put(in_data)
        return None, pyaudio.paContinue

    def generator(self):
        while not self.closed:
            chunk = self._buff.get()
            if chunk is None:
                return
            data = [chunk]

            # Now consume whatever other data's still buffered.
            while True:
                try:
                    chunk = self._buff.get(block=False)
                    if chunk is None:
                        return
                    data.append(chunk)
                except queue.Empty:
                    break

            yield b''.join(data)
# [END audio_stream]


def listen_print_loop(responses):
    num_chars_printed = 0
    for response in responses:
        if not response.results:
            continue

        result = response.results[0]
        if not result.alternatives:
            continue

        # Display the transcription of the top alternative.
        transcript = result.alternatives[0].transcript

        overwrite_chars = ' ' * (num_chars_printed - len(transcript))

        if not result.is_final:
            sys.stdout.write(transcript + overwrite_chars + '\r')
            sys.stdout.flush()

            num_chars_printed = len(transcript)

        else:
            print(transcript + overwrite_chars)

            if re.search(r'\b(exit|quit)\b', transcript, re.I):
                print('Exiting..')
                break

            num_chars_printed = 0


def main():
    language_code = 'en-US'  # a BCP-47 language tag

    client = speech.SpeechClient()
    config = types.RecognitionConfig(
        encoding=enums.RecognitionConfig.AudioEncoding.LINEAR16,
        sample_rate_hertz=RATE,
        language_code=language_code)
    streaming_config = types.StreamingRecognitionConfig(
        config=config,
        interim_results=True)

    with MicrophoneStream(RATE, CHUNK) as stream:
        audio_generator = stream.generator()
        requests = (types.StreamingRecognizeRequest(audio_content=content)
                    for content in audio_generator)

        responses = client.streaming_recognize(streaming_config, requests)

        # Now, put the transcription responses to use.
        listen_print_loop(responses)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Answer (score 1):

Late answer but I write it anyway : 
Google speech has a hard timeout set at 60s. You cannot stream more than 60s via grpc to it. 
A workaround is to restart the grpc call every 55 seconds for example.